# Posting sketchup drawing for review

Tags: discussion

Can I post sketchup files (as links) for review.

For example, I'm drawing a fold up bench for the garage. Can I post the drawings as a question to get feedback on my design?

Answer (score 5):

It depends.  First you need to ask specific question(s) on the design, not 'have any opinions?'  Which sometimes happens.

I'm not sure what our policy is on linking in the designs, since we want the questions to be mostly self-sufficient, and not have to worry about the links dying.

So I would recommend having at least one of the drawings embedded in the question, and link to the rest.  The most useful one for the question.

And remember you can always ask multiple questions if you need.

Comment: Agreed. If there is s_specific_ question, eg will it bear seight, that's one tjing (though it isn't clear how many of us can do more than refer you to the Sagulator and such). Beyond that... well , there are good reasons Code Review is its own topic, and I'd argue they apply to woodworking design review too.

Comment: I agree; the question should be of a technical nature rather than a qualitative nature, and the Sketchup should be exported as a PNG and embedded rather than simply linked, though it's ok to include a link in addition to embedding an image.

Comment: I agree too.  If you're not exactly sure what type of questions would make it valid, give it your best shot and we can all comment/flag as appropriate.  Definitely embed at least one image from the SketchUp though.